# How to remove `httpd` (apache) without removing config files with `yum`

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have wanted to remove and reinstall the `apache` (package name: `httpd` in RHEL variant)  application without removing its configuration with `yum.`

Distro: Centos 7

Comment: `rm httpd` ?  What distro? How was it installed?

Comment: I tried removing with yum remove httpd but it removes config files too.

Comment: Why not just backup the files you want to keep?

Comment: I can do that but I am searching if there is a prebuilt way to do what I want.

Comment: What's your next step: Installing a different version, or different HTTP software?  Do you want the RPM database to know that you removed it?

Comment: I just wanted to reinstall it without changing anything(config and contents).

Answer (score 1):

As I know Centos does not remove files modified(but I am not 100% sure)
debian did it(for this reason apt can use purge to remove them).
So you must did this(I don't want responsibility if you miss file..better backup the entire disk first)

First backup of files

```
tar -cvf backup.tar.gz /etc/httpd /var/www/html
```

Then remove

```
yum remove httpd
```

If yum remove files that you need,you can easily recover from backup

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to take backup. I wanted a `flag` like something. But didn't find anything so I asked for any best practice to do this.